# How can I program optional client side decorations in gtk?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gnome, gtkmm

I'm trying to implement optional client side decorations for my GTK application. In order to do this, I created a subclass of window, with the argument use_csd in the constructor. I created a boxlayout in which I added my two widgets: `Gtk::HeaderBar` and `graphing_area`:

```
class MyWindow : public Gtk::Window {
 public:
  MyWindow(bool use_csd = true);
 protected:
  GraphingArea graphing_area_;
  Gtk::HeaderBar header_bar_;
  Gtk::Button new_tab_button_;
  Gtk::Box vbox_;
};


MyWindow::MyWindow(bool use_csd) : vbox_(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL) {

  Glib::ustring title = "Test";
  // set_decorated(false);
  new_tab_button_.set_image_from_icon_name("tab-new", Gtk::ICON_SIZE_BUTTON, true);
  header_bar_.pack_start(new_tab_button_);
  // set_titlebar(header_bar_);

  if (use_csd) {
    set_titlebar(header_bar_);
    add(graphing_area_);
    header_bar_.set_show_close_button();
    header_bar_.set_title(title);
  } else {
    set_title(title);
    add(vbox_);
    vbox_.pack_start(header_bar_, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);
    vbox_.pack_end(graphing_area_);
  }


  show_all_children();
}
```

I got this result with `use_csd = true`

[image: Window with client side decorations]

and this result with `use_csd = false`

[image: Window without client side decorations]

Am I doing this correctly? How do I remove the white corner in the top left area?

Comment: seems to be related to css.. you can try using gtk inspector to check if some css is being applied to make the corner round.

Comment: In the `use_csd = false` case, have you tried not using a `Gtk::HeaderBar`? Instead, you could simply have some container with the same background color as the titlebar and add your top left widget to it. It seems to me like header bars are made to be displayed at the top of the window.